# Apache tomcat 8.5 not getting started from eclipse photon. with JDK 8.022/ JDK 11

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, java-8

I tried 64 bit of tomcat 9 with JDK 11 and 32 bit of tomcat 8.5 with JDK 8 on windows 10 64 bit OS with eclipse photon.

local host page is getting loaded only when the tomcat service is running in services list. When I try to manually start the tomcat from eclipse it shows ports already occupied. After that i stop the tomcat service from windows services list, and retry starting from eclipse tomcat.

Then the server is getting started on console , but its not loading any java web app nor even local host page.

Because of this i m not able to run any java web app from eclipse.

I already tried deleting and readding server. changing jdk and even tomcat versions, but same issue every time.

Please provide a solution that will work for sure.

Comment: Do you have a project to deploy to Tomcat from Eclipse? It's unclear where you are stuck after having stopped the installed service.

Comment: I have Java web project as well, but when I start tomcat from server tab of eclipse ,even it's getting started,local Host  admin page is giving 404 and even web app giving 404.

Comment: its esolved now